# Spring JPA writing a native query with parameters inside single quotes

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

```
@Repository
public class PostgresRepository {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void updatePassword(PostgresDto postgresDto) {

    Query result = entityManager.createNativeQuery("ALTER ROLE :username PASSWORD :password ")
            .setParameter(1,postgresDto.getUsername())
            .setParameter(2,postgresDto.getPassword());
    int results = result.executeUpdate();

    }
}
```

I am trying to have spring JPA change the role password of a postgres database through the native query. Having issues in setting the parameters of the native query. The postgres statement for altering a role are as follows `ALTER ROLE username PASSWORD 'password'`.

ERROR :

```
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
... 138 common frames omitted
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Position: 12
```

Answer (score 1):

With keyword missing in query. It should be:

```
ALTER ROLE :username WITH PASSWORD :password
```

Comment: this will not work as a native query as the alter role statement is something like ALTER ROLE davide WITH PASSWORD 'hu8jmn3'; and single quotes are parsed out of the parameters with JPA native query